# Reading tag values from xml file using Python code.

Tags: python, xml

I need to read three parameters from xml tag from my test result output file.  The xml file looks like the below sample:

```
-<statistics>

+<total>
<tag> </tag>
-<suite>
<stat name="SignIn" id="s1" pass="1" fail="0">SignIn</stat>
</suite>

</statistics>
```

I have to read values for name, pass and fail from the above sub tag 'suite'. (I need to do this for 'N' number of xml output files and send the cumulative test metrics to the other teams of the project)

Please provide me the code snippet in Python.

Thanks in advance,
Ishwar.

Comment: Are the files as simple as this? Are there other `<stat>` tags within the file or just the one under `<suite>`? Reason I ask is because you can easily do this with an xml library (I always use lxml) but if it was _really_ simple you could more easily do it with a regex.

Comment: The Statistics is one of the tag from the test result file 'SignIn_Output.xml'.

Comment: Yes Aidan,  I have around 10 xml files and all are having the tag 'Statistics' which gives test result for that file.. and I need to read Filename, Total Pass and Total Fail values..

Comment: That doesn't exactly answer Aidan's question. Does each xml file only have a single `<stat ...>...</stat>` entry?

Comment: Yes...The entire xml file has only one sub tag <stat>... </stat> under the main tag Statistics...

Answer (score 0):

As Aidan Kane says, in general, it's better to use a proper XML / HTML parsing library such as lxml (or Beautiful Soup), but when the XML structure is predictable and simple it's ok to use a regular expression (aka regex) to extract data.

So if the fields in a `stat` tag are always the same (and in the same order) as given above, you can do this to extract the name, pass and fail:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

s = '''-<statistics>

+<total>
<tag> </tag>
-<suite>
<stat name="SignIn" id="s1" pass="1" fail="0">SignIn</stat>
</suite>

</statistics>
'''


def main():
    import re

    print s

    pat = re.compile(r'<stat name="(.*?)" id=".*?" pass="(.*?)" fail="(.*?)">.*?</stat>')
    print pat.search(s).groups()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**output**

```
-<statistics>

+<total>
<tag> </tag>
-<suite>
<stat name="SignIn" id="s1" pass="1" fail="0">SignIn</stat>
</suite>

</statistics>

('SignIn', '1', '0')
```